# How to use swingbox in java

Tags: java

I am creating a web browser in which I have to render CSS. Now I have done the HTML part with JEditorPane but I have trouble trying to incorporate swingbox. Following is my code

```
private JTextField addressBar;
   private JEditorPane display;
private void load(String Url){
       try {
           display.setPage(Url);
           addressBar.setText(Url);
          BrowserPane swingbox = new BrowserPane();
            // add the component to your GUI
          display.add(swingbox);
           // display the page
           swingbox.setPage(Url);           
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(MiniBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }
```

It displays HTML but without CSS. Here is the error that it displays on console:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: This message is a warning, not an error, it means you don't have any slf4j api implementation on your classpath, so it falls back to the no-op implementation

Comment: @RC. Then why does it not render CSS?

Comment: OK, I surrender, this message is now an error that blocks your css rendering!? (Note that adding an SLF4J implementation would remove this "error")